# Remove Category from Product Page title

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to remove the category from the product page title but I somehow can't get it to work.

Could anyone of you possibly help me ?

[image: It says TITLE and then it displays the category]

It says TITLE and then it displays the category

I was trying to remove

```
 <h1 class="title"><span><?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle(); ?></span></h1>
```

From the breadcrumbs.phtml but it removes the whole thing.

Thanks in advance

Armin

Comment: I would search .phtml files for a unique class/id surrounding the content you want to remove to find out what file it generates from. There's always the css option as well.

Comment: Thanks Email - I I did search in the phtml - the trouble is however that there is only one call `   <h1 class="title"><span><?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle(); ?></span></h1>` and when I remove this the entire text gets removed.

Answer (score 0):

Put below code into your breadcrumb.phtml file.

```
<?php foreach($crumbs as $_crumbName=>$_crumbInfo): ?>
    <?php if($_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
        <?php
            $result =  $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']);
            $resultorg = $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']);
            if(strlen($result)>80) { 
                $result = substr($result, 0, 40); 
            }
        ?> 
        <strong class="em-breadcrumbs-title"><?php echo $this->__($result);?><?php if(strlen($resultorg) > 40): ?> <?php echo $this->__(' ...');?><?php endif; ?></strong>        
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If Title is more than 40 then cut the string and display "..." after the Title.

I think this may be help.

[image]

Comment: Hi - It did not work unfortunately. All it did was adding another line of text below